# DNS unable to resolve certain specific hostnames (eg fortune.com) Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dns, 17.04

Recently my Ubuntu 17.04 has not been able to resolve some hosts (test: http://www.fortune.com); the [site is up](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/fortune.com), and with the *same laptop* and *same router (and ISP)* dual-booted into windows, I can access the site.

Currently:

```
$ ping fortune.com 
ping: fortune.com: Name or service not known

$ nslookup fortune.com 
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find fortune.com: No answer

$ dig fortune.com     
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> fortune.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50367
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fortune.com.           IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 16 06:19:32 PDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40

$ grep fortune.com /etc/hosts
{nothing}
```

The `/etc/resolve.conf` has only `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, which apparently is normal.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Here's an excerpt from `systemd-resolve --status` :

```
Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
```

Trying `dig @8.8.8.8 fortune.com`, I get the following:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 fortune.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64088
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fortune.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.243
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.134
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.109
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.9
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.135
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.225
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.176
fortune.com.        59  IN  A   52.84.243.62

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 16 14:49:37 PDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 168
```

Note: none of those IP addresses are actually accessible via the browser (but maybe that's by design); browsing directly to those URLs ( http://52.84.243.9 ) returns:

```
ERROR The request could not be satisfied. Bad request.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

Is this "success"? Is the work-around changing my DNS servers to google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4?)?  But what's the *actual* problem?

**Edit:** I tried wifi at a cafe instead of my home comcast wifi, and still can't access the site.  Diagnostics the same: `dig @8.8.8.8 fortune.com` returns the same, contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are still `127.0.0.53`. No change even though I was finally able to add "additional DNS servers" to this cafe wifi connection for both IPv4 and IPv6 ("Save" is enabled -- but I don't know why it's read-only on my home wifi). As expected, `systemd-resolve --status` returns `10.1.10.1` instead of `192.168.1.1`. Otherwise, still stumped.

Is there something weird about Ubuntu DNS + resolving the domain name `fortune.com` ?

Comment: It seems that your systemd-resolve points to your router as DNS: 192.168.1.1 .. what DNS does that thingie use ?

Comment: What if you use something like `dig @8.8.8.8 fortune.com`?

Comment: @sorenA I don't know why that is showing up, there are so many layers of indirection in ubuntu dns that I can't follow the thread. I'll undo my first attempt at fixing this and see if it reports the same. But I literally don't see where my DNS info is coming from, prior or after that change, and attempts to set it manually just get overwritten.

Comment: @Ravexina I added the output from running that `dig` -- it does return actual results, which I guess is good, but I'm not sure how to test if those results are "correct", other than setting my DNS to use opendns/google, which I'll try now (previously attempts to set them manually keep getting overwritten/ignored)

Comment: still, if ubuntu-DNS is somehow broken, and resetting dns to 8.8.8.8/etc is the solution, I imagine others would have the same issue, but there are so many "ubuntu + DNS" questions that I'm unable to find this exact issue. It's not a new router -- literally unchanged in years. Could be due to in-place upgrade to 17.04, which was in the past couple months (I forget exactly).

Comment: When you don't set any DNS, ubuntu will resolve your DNS requests by sending them to your router and your router will forward them to your ISP's DNS Server, so something is wrong with your ISP's DNS Server (I Guess), use NetworkManager and set a reliable DNS Server like google or anything else which you like.

Comment: @Ravexina I agree, that was my first thought. But rebooting that same laptop into windows (it's dual-boot), I can access the same site without a problem, so I'm currently ruling out my ISP (which is comcast -- hence my initial suspicion). Network manager presently not allowing me to "Save" updated DNS -- button is not enabled to save the changes.

Comment: Use `nmcli` using `sudo` => `sudo nmcli connection modify CONNECTION-NAME ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`, if without sudo it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is, apparently, "user-error", as the issue is a result of manual configuration.  I have a lot of hosts listed in `/etc/hosts` that are "blocked" by disabling DNS resolution: for these hosts, I set the IP to manually resolve to `0.0.0.0`; this is for sites that are purely ads/pop-ups/suspicious/etc.

I initially thought `/etc/hosts` could be a problem, but I did *not* have any host in there with domain `fortune.com`.  After some trial and error, I was able to determine that disabling the hostname `*.webtrendslive.com` (by setting its IP address to 0.0.0.0) also somehow disables `fortune.com`. Net effect: I can "ping" webtrendslive.com, which resolves to 127.0.0.1, but can't ping `fortune.com`, receiving instead error "Name or service not known".  Even though I can chalk this up to user-error, I don't actually understand what caused this (feel free to enlighten me, anyone.)